# Encoding categorical data issue

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, encoding

I was doing a house price regression model and I got the [data](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques) from Kaggle, and when I try to convert the categorical variables to dummy variables I got something unusual for the training data, I got the shape of `(1460, 270)`

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,
19,20,21,22,23,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,
33,37,38,39,40,51,53,55,57,60,61,62,72,73
])], remainder='passthrough',sparse_threshold=0)
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))

X.shape
(1460, 270)
```

when I did the same for the test data, I got the shape of `(1459, 254)`

```
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,
19,20,21,22,23,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,
33,37,38,39,40,51,53,55,57,60,61,62,72,73
])], remainder='passthrough',sparse_threshold=0)
X_actual = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X_actual))

X_actual.shape
(1459, 254)
```

Why the shape is different after converting the same categorical variables for the train and the test data.

Note that before converting the categorical variables, there was no issue both data have the same shape;  that issue only happened when I convert the same categorical variables for both data sets, I got different shapes.

I did a solution, but I do not like it so much, I resize the X_actual.shape to `(1459,270)`, and the algorithm works fine, but I think it affects the algorithm quality too much. And, if it is normal when converting categorical variables for two different data sets, how I can make both data set have the same dimensions?

Comment: can you format the code properly, so we can have more information to work with?

Comment: Welcome to SO; please *format** your code snippets accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are re-fitting [`OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) to the test data `X_actual` using `fit_transform` again, so it seems that `X_actual` has fewer categories (and possibly new ones). Try instead `ct.transform(X_actual)` to preserve all the categories found in the training data `X`, and hence the feature shape.

---

Note that `OneHotEncoder`, as of the current version of scikit-learn 1.0.2, with the default parameter `handle_unknown='error'` will raise an error upon encountering new categories in test data. Set `handle_unknown='ignore'` to ignore the error.

Comment: Thank you so much, ct. transform(X_actual) works fine and the shape of both X_test and X_actual is the same now, and I got an enormous improvement for the algorithm result.